# Let $R$ be a Artinian commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$. If $I$ is prime, then $I$ is maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove: Let $R$ a Artinian commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$. If $I$ is prime, then $I$ is maximal.

---

I got stuck on this. I understand that every ideal is generated by finitely many elements. Here is my approach:

It's enough to prove the following implication:
$$ R/I \ \text{is a domain} \quad \Rightarrow \quad R/I \ \text{is a field}$$
Then only finding an inverse is left. So let $x \in R$ in arbitrary. We have to find an inverse element of $x+I \in R/I$, that as an element y so that $x \cdot y \in I+1$.
We denote $I = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$. 
Now I have to find y so that $xy -1 = r_1 x_1+ r_2 x_2 + \cdots + r_n x_n$. This is where I no more knew what to do.

Your advise will be appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing in your assumptions that imply all ideals are finitely generated. And having all ideals finitely generated is not enough for this anyway.

Comment: Koen, what makes you think prime ideals are maximal? What makes you think domains are fields?

Comment: I would guess you wrote the problem down wrong. We do have the implication if $I$ is maximal then $I$ is prime. On the other hand, you could just be missing an assumption that $R$ has finitely many elements.

Comment: In response to your edit: $\mathbb Z$ is a Noetherian ring which fails to satisfy your claim.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say that R must be noetherian

Comment: That's not enough for your claim to be true. I gave a counterexample in an earlier comment, and so did Simone in an answer.

Comment: Well, that's strange. In that case my syllabus is wrong.

Comment: Could you tell us where you got this from?

Comment: http://www.science.uva.nl/~geer/algebra2-input.pdf 
Page 35, exercise 20. This is the syllabus we use. The only problem about for you is that it has been written in Dutch.

Comment: Exercise 20 says: "Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\neq 0$. Assume that every sequence $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset \cdots$ stabilises. Prove that every prime ideal is maximal. Prove that $R$ is a field if it has no zero divisors.

Comment: @KoenvanDuin That changes everything because that is the *Artinian* condition. The Noetherian condition is about *ascending* chains.

Answer (score 9):

Your clarification in the comments saying that "every descending chain stabilizes" is the Artinian condition, not the Noetherian condition.

Let $M$ be a prime ideal of an Artinian ring $R$. Then $R/M$ is a prime Artinian ring, but such rings are simple (isomorphic to a matrix ring over a division ring!), so by correspondence of ideals in $R/M$ with ideals between $M$ and $R$, $M$ is necessarily a maximal ideal.

Your approach for the commutative case is good one, and it's just a special case of this. Since $R$ is Artinian, so is $R/M$. But $R/M$ is a domain, and an Artinian domain is a field. Thus, $M$ is maximal.

Showing an Artinian domain is a field is also pretty easy: suppose that $aR\neq R$. By examining the chain $aR\supseteq a^2R\supseteq\dots$ you will be able to show $a=0$.

Comment: Your answer is nice and concise, but reading through it there is something I did not understand. How do we know that a prime Artinian ring is simple?

Comment: @LinearAlgebra that is a consequence of the artin-Wedderburn theorem.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't quite understand this. Could you please elaborate a little bit. How exactly is the Artin-Wedderburn theorem used to prove that?

Comment: @LinearAlgebra Prime rings have radical zero, so the a-w theorem asserts it is a product of matrix rings over division rings, but being prime, there cannot be more than one matrix ring. Thus you're left with a single matrix ring which is simple.

Comment: Let me try to grasp this…. So if we have the nil radical of R, which is the sum of all nil two sided ideals of R, how could it be zero if R is a prime ring?

Comment: @LinearAlgebra the a-w theorem is phrased in terms of the Jacobson radical, not the upper nilradical. (But maybe they coincide in artinian rings!) For artinian rings, having Jacobson radical zero and being semiprime are equivalent. If you need a reference for this I can give several. Prime rings are semiprime, so artinian prime rings satisfy the a-w hypotheses.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I think I am understanding parts of it slowly, but then why is a prime ring cannot have more than one matrix ring in it's product?

Comment: @LinearAlgebra I know you can see this one on your own: suppose you look at the direct product of two nonzero rings. Show that there are two nonzero ideals multiplying to zero. (There is nothing tricky about these two ideals: think as simply as possible!)

Comment: I think I understand. If we have the direct product for rings $A$ and $B$, we can define two ideals as, $I_1=\{(a,\,0)\,|\,a\in A\}$ and $I_2=\{(0,\, b)\,|\,b\in B\}$ and these two ideals when multiplied together will give zero. Is that correct?

Comment: @LinearAlgebra yep! Good job

Comment: Thanks so much, I think I now understand the problem quite well. Going through what you said before over and over again, I should be able to understand the proof. Thanks again, and hope you have a nice day. :)

Comment: @LinearAlgebra awesome :) good luck!

Answer (score 4):

It's not generally true that every prime ideal is maximal in a commutative ring. Take for example the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and the ideal $(2)$. It's prime, but it's not maximal, for example $(2)\subset (2,x)\neq\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, if you look for a commutative ring where all prime ideals are maximal you have to take an Artinian ring. I think this is the largest case where it holds.

Comment: A Dedekind domain is not necessarily Artinian, but it has this property.

Comment: @Andy Domains have the property that $\{0\}$ is prime. If that ideal is maximal, then it's a field and fields are artinian.

Comment: @user1 You're right of course. My statement is true if we don't consider $(0)$ though. So Simone is right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @simone Artinian rings are not the "largest case." For a commutative ring, having all prime ideals maximal is equivalent to R/rad(R) Von Neumann regular and rad(R) nil. There are many such nonartinian rings, but the Artinian condition does imply both of these hypotheses.